# Android: going back to first fragment by pressing home button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on a simple android application that has MainActivity with FragmentStatePagerAdapter and some number of fragments side by side. I want to be able to go to the first fragment by pressing home button.

I know my code is pretty bad. Still I hope just a few lines will solve my problem.

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.freestylers.druskischool;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;
FragmentStatePagerAdapter adapter; 


* Each page of our pager will display one fragment from this array
* Swiping, to the right will take you to the next page
*/
 String[] fragments={
    "start",
    "mes",
    "whatever",
    "next",
    "name",
    "of",
    "a",
    "fragment",
    "more fragments",
    "and",
    "more",
    "fragments"

};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.my_pager);

    adapter=new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(
        //maybe should use normal getFragmentManager()
            getSupportFragmentManager()
        ){

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // This makes sure getItem doesn't use a position
           // that is out of bounds of our array of fragments
           return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // Here is where all the magic of the adapter happens
            // As you can see, this is really simple.
            //(fragments[position]);
                if(position==0){
                return StartFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==1){
                return MesFragment.newInstance();
                }
                else if(position==2){
                returnNextFragment.newInstance();
                }
                //this goes on until position==11
                else{return StartFragment.newInstance();}

        }

    };

    //Let the pager know which adapter it is supposed to use
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);  
}  



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And this is one of my fragments, MesFragment. On the line 19 (commented out by double slash)I just don`t know which command to use to get to my first fragment:

```
package com.freestylers.druskischool;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MesFragment extends Fragment {


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
        //(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().??? I don`t know how               

to go back to first fragment
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (getActivity()).getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    View view=inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_mes, 
        container, 
        false);


    return view;
}

// This is the method the pager adapter will use
// to create a new fragment
public static Fragment newInstance(){
    MesFragment f=new MesFragment();

    return f;
 }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are on the right track. Assuming you already added it your stack,  try this: getSupportFragmentManager().hide(oldFragment); getSupportFragmentManager().show(firstFragment);

Comment: Unfortunately doesn`t work that way, when i try .hide(MesFragment) it cannot be resolved to a variable and when i try .hide(MesFragment.class) method hide(class<MesFragment>) is undefined for the type FragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

You can set the currently selected item using ViewPager, which is in your activity:

```
public void switchToMesFragment() {
        pager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
```

To switch from within a fragment, you need to get a reference to your activity and call the switching function, like so:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).switchToMesFragment();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot completely control the Home button key since it is a key that is broadcasted to all active apps on the device. If you want to process the Home button for your app, you may overrride the Activity.`onPause`() method. Documentation @ [Pausing an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html). But still you cannot prevent the user from seeing the Home screen, that's not fair to other apps perhaps.  Try this out first...